# Facebook like issue (disappears on refresh)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a facebook app that load some content with ajax, including some like buttons implemented with iframe.

While everything seems ok and in my pc is working properly, in my clients pc it does not work and the json response of 'like' is : 307 temporary redirect.

At first i thought that it must have been a firewall issue so i proposed my client to test another application that has 'like' button. Unfortunately, everything was ok in the other app.

The thing that puzzles me is that the structure of the iframe is identical:

*mine*:

```
    <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.chivastimeforfriends.com/single.php?fb_ref=4f15a6ed73f3a&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=150&action=like&font=trebuchet+ms&colorscheme=light&height=21" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:23px;" allowtransparency="true"><iframe>
```

*other app*

```
    <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:80px;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.stolichnaya.gr/stoli/fb/outletitem.php?outid=12&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=150&amp;action=like&amp;font=trebuchet+ms&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21"></iframe>
```

Facebook debugger does not show any problem in my app. The other app has not even meta tags.

The only difference is that while the other app json response is returned in just 2 seconds , in my app takes about 13 second. Has this anything to do with the problem?

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to url_encode the href you send to facebook. You cannot have another `?` sign:

```
...like.php?href=http://www.stolichnaya.gr/stoli/fb/outletitem.php**?**outid=12&amp;...
```

You could use the PHP function url_encode.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

```
<?php
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
?>
```

Comment: Yes, i have already tried that.. Plus if this was the problem , then everybody should have the same issue as my client

Comment: I am talking about encoding your url (what comes after `like.php?href=<encoded url>`)

Comment: Yes i have already tried this, and makes no difference to my clients pc

Comment: Can you try to remove fb_ref parameter?

Comment: Yes i can remove it but this querystring is vital for the like url. Besides the other app has also a get parameter (outid).

Comment: I see... Did you try to generate the like button using their builder? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Yep, both in html5 and fb tag implementation. I had a problem with fb implementation because of the ajax loaded content by i solved it with the fb.parse method. But still it didnt work

Comment: I think it is working now. I clicked on 'like' on your fb app and posted the url on my wall and it displayes the like as clicked on your page even after refresh.

Comment: I know! That the really irrating fact. That it works everywhere except for my clients pc.